# Posted picture link undefined using Facebook JS SDK

Tags: javascript, image, facebook

I am trying to get the link of the posted pictures from someone's profile using the Facebook JS SDK.

I am able to console.log the id of the picture, but the picture link is undefined.

When I use the Graph Api Explorer i can see the link of the picture, but when I want to use it in my website, its undefined..

This is the code I use:

```
var photosArray = [];

function statusChangeCallback(response){
   if (response.status === 'connected') {
     console.log('je bent ingelogd!');
     FB.api('/me?fields=name,email,birthday,location,likes,events,posts,picture.width(200).height(200),photos', function(response){
       if(response && !response.error){
         buildProfile(response);
       }else{
         console.log("no response");
       }
     })
   }else{
     console.log('je bent uitgelogd!');
   }
 }

function buildProfile(user){
      for(i=0; i<user.posts.data.length; i++){
      photosArray.push(user.posts.data[i].id + user.posts.data[i].picture );
    };

    fbUserProfile.photos = photosArray;

    console.log(photosArray);

        for(i=0; i<user.posts.data.length; i++){
          photosArray.push(user.posts.data[i].id + user.posts.data[i].picture.link );
        };
        fbUserProfile.photos = photosArray;
        console.log(photosArray);
    };
```

The console.log result:

[console.log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xextE.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post the response?

Comment: Check the console.log result image in the question.

Comment: please include all the relevant code, especially the part with the api call

Comment: You are not _asking_ for the post picture in your field list, so you only get the two default fields id and created_at for each post. Tip, you can also test such requests in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) first ... maybe that helps in the future to realize that this did not give you all the data you expected to begin with.

Comment: Thanks @04FS, I am new to the Facebook JS SDK.. so I forgot to put {picture} after the post request. Have a nice day ;)